# How to get as.POSIXct to not change timezone of string?

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

This has been causing me problems for a while. I have a column of date-time strings like this:

```
"2016-09-13 22:27:37.320 UTC"
```

And I have been trying to get them coerced into POSIXct objects using:

```
library(anytime)
final$contact <- as.POSIXct(anytime(final$contact, tz="UTC"))
```

But it gives me the time as if I'd converted it from my local timezone (EST) to UTC, despite my inclusion of UTC in the string, then specifying in anytime that the tz is UTC:

```
2016-09-14 02:27:37
```

The ultimate end-goal of this is to pass them into this:

```
for (i in 1:NROW(final$first_rpc)){
    final$localcontact[i] <- format(final$contact[i],
                                    tz=as.character(final$timezone.x[i]),
                                    usetz = TRUE)
}
```

So that each time uses its respective timezone instead of UTC (which is how the data is stored in our database).

This is about the fourth version of this I've tried and I really have no idea how to make it work the way I'd like, where the string up there is converted into as POSIXct object still in UTC. Is there any way to make anytime/as.POSIXct realize that these are in UTC already?

Comment: Why do you need to wrap with `anytime`?  Just do `as.POSIXct(str1, tz = "UTC")#
[1] "2016-09-13 22:27:37 UTC"`

Comment: I honestly don't know anymore, at one point the strings were poorly formatted and it wouldn't work at all, so I used anytime and I've just left it in since it wasn't hurting anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x <- "2016-09-13 22:27:37.320 UTC"
as.POSIXct(x, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz ='EST')
[1] "2016-09-13 22:27:37 EST"
```

Comment: Yes but this leaves it as EST in the POSIXct object, not UTC. So when I do the local conversion it will be wrong still. Can I change the timezone without changing the datetime itself?

Comment: Whatever you pass to `tz` will be the timezone, without affecting the hours count. You can pass 'UTC'.

Comment: oh man I'm dumb yeah it is that easy. Thank you! (Will accept when minimum time has passed)

Comment: A variation of this worked for me.  I have a UTC time string that ggplot didn't like too much.  

`x <- "2020-01-21T16:58:59Z"
as.POSIXct.default(x,format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", tz = "UTC")
[1] "2020-01-21 16:58:59 UTC"
`

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to include both the usetz and tz parameters to get `as.POSIXct` to honor the UTC designation. The %z and %Z formats are for output only:

```
as.POSIXct(x, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", usetz=TRUE, tz="UTC")
#[1] "2016-09-13 22:27:37 UTC"
```

`anytime (from package by the same name) uses different parameter names:

```
anytime::anytime(x, asUTC=TRUE)
[1] "2016-09-13 15:27:37 PDT"  # value came in as UTC but the default print output is local
anytime::anytime(x, asUTC=TRUE, tz="UTC")  # overrides local tz conversion
[1] "2016-09-13 22:27:37 UTC"
```

Like your unnamed database (perhaps homegrown) R stores all date-time objects as UTC and it's only at output that a timezone designator is applied. If you have a mixture of timezones coming in then yu will need to preprocess them and store the associated source TZ as character values before sending to `strptime` or `as.POSIXct`, as you are already anticipating.

Answer (score 2):

We don't need to specify the `format` here as it is already in the `Date Time` format

```
as.POSIXct(str1, tz = "UTC")
#[1] "2016-09-13 22:27:37 EDT"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "2016-09-13 22:27:37.320 UTC"
```

Comment: Tbh I think this is the best answer.