# Convert timestamp with offset to offset's timezone

Tags: r, date, timezone

Given a timestamp with an offset, I want to convert to a POSIXct object and ensure that the timezone is what is provided by the offset.

Take the following example:

```r
t_stamp <- "20180812 17:32:00.000 -0700"

as.POSIXct(
  t_stamp,
  format = "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%OS %z"
)
```

This works great but it automatically converts to my computer's timezone. Is there a way to not convert to my timezone but use whichever TZ was in the -0700 offset?

Edit:

The output of the above on my computer is `"2018-08-12 20:32:00 EDT"`. However, the `-0700` indicates that the timezone is `PDT`. I would like that timezone to be used. But I want to be flexible and provide the timezone programmatically for example the offset could be `-0400` to indicate EDT and I would want EDT as the timezone.

So explicitly setting the `tz` argument with a name from the Olson database is not a possibility.

Comment: `%z` is used to format output, and you'll need to specify a time zone. You can set a time zone such as `as.POSIXct(t_stamp, format = '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%OS, tz = 'MST)`. 

[see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52879021/how-to-get-as-posixct-to-not-change-timezone-of-string)

Comment: The `format` argument is how `strptime()` handles the conversion from character to a date format. The `%z` indicates that the timestamp has a timezone offset. I want to use the timezone offset to determine the timezone.

Comment: I think you want to do a mapping, so build a table with all possible shifts and their tz. There are many different tz for the same shift so you have to decide which you want to use , please refer to `base::OlsonNames()`.

Answer (score 1):

As I suggested in the comment, one option is to create the mapping table and apply it through all strings.
I used the `stringr::str_replace_all` function to simplify the translation process.
Please edit the mapping table manually if needed, with suited you timezones.
You can use the `base::OlsonNames()` function to get all timezone names.

```r
t_stamps <- c("20180812 17:32:00.000 -0700", "20180812 17:32:00.000 -0800", "20180812 17:32:00.000 +1200")

# Please edit manually
# Example
map_tab <- data.frame(
  tz = paste0("\\", sprintf("%+03d00", seq(-12, 12, 1))), 
  tz_name = sprintf("GMT%+1.0f", seq(-12, 12, 1))
)

stringr::str_replace_all(t_stamps, setNames(as.character(map_tab$tz_name), map_tab$tz))
#> [1] "20180812 17:32:00.000 GMT-7"  "20180812 17:32:00.000 GMT-8" 
#> [3] "20180812 17:32:00.000 GMT+12"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>